# python a exe, Selenium dentro de ventanas

Tags: python, selenium, exe

Les dejo el codigo completo de mi programa en Python 2.7

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0L1ZT-zXzKlZ3BTbm5zU0p6VTA/view?usp=sharing

Estoy buscando hacerle un par de agregados pero no se de que manera y con que programas me conviene hacerlo. Necesito primero que nada convertirlo a ejecutable.exe. Por otro lado me gustaria que ya que trabajo con selenium pueda crearle una ventana donde se ejecute el selenium y no que me abra un navegador. Me refiero a una ventana donde me vaya mostrando todo lo que va ocurriendo en el selenium. No se si algo de lo que pregunto es posible.

Gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A la primera pregunta sobre como generar un archivo exe desde python, existen varias opciones, la que yo suelo recomendar es py2exe, pero aqui hay otras:

1. [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/)
2. [pyinstaller](https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/)
3. [Freezer](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/freezer)

Con py2exe puedes incluir las librerias que usas o dependencias de directorios. Los otros permiten tambien ser usados en otros SO generando los ejecutables del propio SO en el que se ejecutan, no solo para windows.

Respecto a crear una interfaz tan simple o compleja como necesites, yo usaria [PyQt](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/), tiene una excelente documentacion con ejemplos.

Y respecto a si Selenium puedes hacerlo con [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/download.html) y cambiar la apertura del driver:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
```

por:

```
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
```